# Tomcat with datanucleus

Tags: java

Is it possible to  use google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory class in tomcat application
I'm trying to use KeyFactory.createKey in datanucleus tomcat application.But it is throwing error.Can anyone tell me how to use it?Below is the error I`m getting

java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:108)
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:118)
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.(Key.java:104)
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.(Key.java:92)
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:72)
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:57)

Comment: @TomJ Many Many thanks for ur help.But I have my jars already in my Web-inf/libraries.But still am getting the above error.Could you please help me on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External libraries (the jar files themselves) for Tomcat projects go in your projects `WEB-INF/lib` folder

Comment: could anyone please helpme on this question?